# Should I use `Date()` to store a date without time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to store in the backend a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`;
I've initially used in the frontend a js `Date()` object to store it, and dropping the time and timezone info while sending it to the backend; but that caused a "timezone issue" when parsing back the `yyyy-mm-dd` string into `Date()`;

even if it's possible to workaround that issue I was wondering if using a simple `String` wouldn't be better; is there any drawback that now I cannot see and so I should use a `Date` anyway?

Comment: `Date` represents a date+time value. I'd stick with `Date` (with a zero time value) for interopability with other libraries and the rest of the JavaScript ecosystem. Don't use strings or a tuple of integers because you can have invalid values like `2019-02-31`.

Comment: How did you break it apart and parse it back? Make sure to use UTC in both places.

Comment: Without seeing the context of how you're using the date, it's impossible to day. You can't transmit an object, it must be stringified at some point. And ECMAScript Date objects inherently have an associated time and two offsets: their own UTC +0 and the host offset of whatever.

Comment: I have also wondered about this point, and I think it depends on what is the application context of the date. For example, a date of birth is a specific date, regardless of which timezone you are reporting in. If you use Date to store it, it will be reported as a different date in different timezones. So, in some application-specific cases, storing date as a string with no time might be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to other comments, I would also recommend sticking with Date instead of strings to prevent browser differences and for ease of use. One note is when setting the date, don't forget to account for day-light savings which might cause a database crash if not accounted for.

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/): Everything you need to know about date in javascript

Comment: How does the OP transmit a Date object from backend storage to a web page or *vice versa* without stringifying it at some point? Date strings like "2019-11-20" do not have an associated timezone (except for the peculiarity of ECMAScript treating them as UTC).